# Why do we consider only liquid-air surface forces in capillary rise?

Tags: forces, fluid-statics, surface-tension, capillary-action

Consider this diagram from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension).

[image]

Now the diagram clearly depicts forces due to three interfaces. But in the derivation of capillary rise, we only consider the force due to Surface Tension of the liquid - air interface.

Why don't we consider the forces due to other interfaces in this derivation?

Comment: See https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=cUbZ16hCsqw&t=414s